# What happened to "quack quixote" ?

Tags: support, moderators

[quack quixote](https://superuser.com/users/12786/quack-quixote) is a moderator of SuperUser, and I realize that he's not been around quite a while. I checked his profile, and he was last seen on July 13th 2010 at 17:17. Does anyone (esp. the moderators) know what happened to him? Has he left Stack Exchange community? Will he be back someday?

Comment: He is in `limbo` and sorely missed! Nobody tagged quite like him...

Comment: I hope that he joins us soon :)

Comment: @Ivo Flipse, @Sathya: I also hope he joins us soon.

Comment: As the time in `limbo` goes a lot slower than here, it can happen `any` moment...

Comment: Has anyone done the obvious and tried his email address?

Comment: @Nifle: I have just sent him an email. I'll share his answer with you if he replies.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have news about quack. He is fine and gives his best to everyone in their endeavors. Below is the copy of our correspondence:

On Sun, Feb 6, 2011 at 11:35 AM, Mehper Cihangir Palavuzlar wrote:

> Hello quack quixote,
>
> I'm Mehper from Super User. We have not seen you for a long time, and
>   we wanted to know if you're OK. We
>   hope everything's fine on your side.
>   There is also a meta question about
>   you: What happened to “quack quixote”
>   ?
>
> We are looking forward to hearing from you.
>
> Best,
>
> Mehper C. Palavuzlar

Re: Where have you been?
From: quack quixote
To: Mehper Cihangir Palavuzlar
Mon, February 7, 2011 1:38:41 AM

> still alive, doing fine.  i.... just
>   don't login there anymore.  no
>   particular reason; guess i got a
>   little burned out on it and wandered
>   off elsewhere.  oddly similar to how i
>   wandered into SU in the first place.
>
> the community's concern is touching. 
>   unnecessary, but touching.  i hope the
>   SU community is doing well; give my
>   best to everyone in their endeavors.
>
> for the record, no, i'm not the age on
>   my profile; i never tell the truth
>   when filling out internet profiles. 
>   and for some reason the system
>   wouldn't let me put 1605 as my birth
>   year.  :p
>
> ~quack quixote

Comment: good to hear from him! yeah!!

Comment: Thank you @Mehper for sending him an email... wonder why none of us did that :\ but it's good to hear from him

Comment: May this serve as a reminder that too much of a good thing can still be bad. Don't kill yourselves my good mods and fellow dedicated members. There's always tomorrow.

Comment: Super User burns through mods at an incredible rate. Pace yourselves, guys!

Comment: Um, his user profile is obsolete now that he's lost the diamond mark of a moderator...