# Idle moderator position

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, moderation, moderators

[quack quixote](https://superuser.com/users/12786/quack-quixote) has left Super User for good ([here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2050/what-happened-to-quack-quixote) is the related post), and he still seems to have the moderator position (obviously idle). I think this position should be granted (by election) to an active & regular user. What does the SU team think of that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

True, and HTG is a mod in title only (by design, honorary title, etc).

Probably we'd award to the 4th place finisher in the previous election

https://superuser.com/election/1

How does everyone feel about that?

edit: this is now complete; quack de-modded and nhinkle modded!

Comment: Who came in 4th again? It would be the most fair off course, though obviously we didn't have 4 votes to help pick the last one.

Comment: That would be @nhinkle (4th) if he accepts, I know @BloodPhilia (5th) is absent because he is doing a lot of work in a zoo and then comes @RandolphPotter (6th) which I think is active. The current moderation runs fine, but what in a few months? I think it would be fine to add him... :)

Comment: Ah well @nhinkle would have been my fourth choice, so I'm definitely for it then ;-P

Comment: I'd go with @nhinkle too

Comment: I'd go with @nhinkle as well.  he would make a great mod, is levelheaded and knows how to moderate.

Comment: I say go for it!

Comment: @TomWijsman Zoo! :D But I'm coming back! :D

Comment: @ivo I need you to contact nhinkle and see if he is up for this

Comment: Apologies for not responding sooner, it has been a very busy day. I would be honored to accept this offer. Thank you everyone for your support, I appreciate it!

Comment: you better come back @BloodPhilia. I miss my slave.

Comment: @studiohack lololol =p

Comment: Grats @nhinkle!